# QWebFrame::evaluateJavaScript vs. script-tag in HTML

Tags: qt, pyqt4, qtwebkit

I want to develop an application that uses QtWebKit and JQuery.

What I need to know is, is there any difference between reading JQuery from a file and evaluateJavaScript it, or embedding it as a script tag within the "page" that is displayed within the widget?

EDIT: It seems that I have this figured out at least partially. evaluateJavaScript will apparently work reliably; but if I do

```
baseurl = QUrl.fromLocalFile(
  QDir.current().absoluteFilePath("doesntexist.html"));
view.setHtml(
  u"""
    <html>
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" 
          src="jquery-1.4.2.js">
        </script>
      </head>
      <body></body>
    </html>""", baseurl);
```

The file is never even read from disk (checked with inotify). this also affects baseurl being initialized with either

```
QUrl("file:/")
QUrl(".");
QUrl();
```

or

```
QUrl("file://")
```

And I have also tried to change the script src parameter to absolute paths on the hard drive, and to a relative path with and without "./" in front.

How do I do it right (aside from the Qt Resource System) to get the script tag to work with local js files? Is this just poorly documented, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Qt Resource System](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/resources.html) and modify your html to something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
      src=":/jquery-1.4.2.js">
```

and don't forget the call macro Q_INIT_RESOURCE in main

or using the evaluateJavaScript

```
connect(view, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), this, SLOT(loadJQuery()));

...

void MainWindow::loadJQuery()
{
  QFile file("jquery-1.4.2.js");
  file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
  view->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript(file.readAll());
}
```

I guess using the resource systems is better.

Comment: read my question -- I asked specifically for a way "aside from Qt resource system".